# Eu não falo bem Português. Está tudo bem para escrever uma resposta?

Tags: suporte, respostas

Se é possivel, em Inglês...

I speak some Poruguese (Portuguese Portuguese), badly, and I write even worse.

I have experience in COBOL and IBM Mainframes, and I know there are Mainframes in Brazil, so I've been attending here for a while, and looking.

Today there was a first question. And a second.

The answers are easy, and only took a few minutes. But, I like to explain to ensure that things are clear, and this proved to be very difficult.

I do need to improve my writing in Portuguese, and my technical vocabulary, but I don't want to burden those who kindly have edited my two answers so far (special thanks to @bigown). If I answer further I will endeavour to use the accented characters (that was just lazy of me, sorry).

I have two questions then: without a detailed explanation, are the answers useful *for this site*; will you all put up with continuing to edit my terrible language?

The first relates to not wanting someone to use code without understanding it. Hopefully if something is too unclear, someone will comment and I can then spend some time replying. Not ideal, but I don't have time for two minutes on the code, and four hours trying to translate the explanation...

The second shouldn't be a big problem, because there don't seem to be many questions (two so far), but I don't want to have people thinking "goodness, there's that guy again, gotta go edit that for sure".

Comment: Hi Bill. Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. I think people will appreciate your help even if you answer in English. I'm also sure we heve many good translators around here. ;)

Comment: It's ok to write in bad Portuguese. I write in bad English :) We will help you.

Comment: I've written badly in both English and Portuguese since Hight School and it was not a problem here or SO. I encourage you to use even Online translations when needed.

Comment: A tip, Mainframe documentation in portuguese is severely difficult to find. Your help in SO will surely be appreciated!

Comment: @NothingsImpossible Yes. English. Japanese. And that is for COBOL, the main Mainframe programming language. DFSORT just in English as far as I know. Let's also say the reading-age of the manuals is quite high. There is a technique to understanding them, even for native-English speakers. I check here every day, and am happy to help if another question comes in. If the OPs ever return is another thing entirely :-)

Comment: And if you have any doubt you can ask on [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/) site ;)

Answer (score 11):

Vou responder em português no bom exemplo da Stack Overflow.
Suas respostas são certamente bem vindas, e nós, como comunidade, garantiremos eventuais adaptações aqui e ali. 
Como brasileiro, várias e várias vezes tive meu Inglês corrigido no Stack Overflow original, e isso foi ótimo! Ao mesmo tempo em que contribuía com a comunidade melhorava meu Inglês.

Pessoalmente acredito que você não só deve responder a pergunta, como tentar explicar em português da melhor maneira que conseguir com o tempo que você tem disponível. Você verá como após algumas semanas as explicações fluirão naturalmente e você não gastará tanto tempo assim elaborando uma resposta.

Deixe conosco a parte de corrigir potenciais erros de português. Tenho certeza que teremos condições de fazer o mesmo bom trabalho de correção aqui que a Stack Overflow original está fazendo com as respostas de usuários dos mais diversos países.

Bem Vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português!

---

**P.S.** Não sei se as outras pessoas concordam comigo, mas acredito que no começo, enquanto seu português não for suficiente para explicar determinados conceitos, você poderia sinalizar sua própria reposta e requisitar correções. Acho isso melhor do que responder em inglês! E também acredito que fique menos cansativo para você do que postar respostas em duas línguas.

**Comentário irônico:** Tive que editar minha resposta várias vezes para corrigir erros de português, mesmo assim ela está longe da perfeição hehehe :D.

Comment: Não entendo por que estão respondendo em inglês aqui.

Comment: E se tiver alguma dúvida pode perguntar no site [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)  ;)

Answer (score 7):

Well, I think that you might explicitly say that you don't speak portuguese in your question or answer and that you want that someone edit and translate it. At least here in meta, this is what commonly happens.

But this is just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: I did that in the first answer, then I have done it in my profile for here. I don't mind doing it in each answer. Are you saying if I answer in English someone will edit it for me? Is that only on Meta, or in the main part. Tempting, though I do need the practice in Portuguese as well...

Comment: @BillWoodger I suggest you write both in English and Portuguese, so we can fix portuguese part when needed.

Comment: @utluiz OK, that's an idea. The Portuguese version will be much later (muito mais tarde) but I feel happier with that than just letting the code dangle there.

Comment: I'd say English is only okay on meta. But bad Portuguese is okay on the site, we can help you fix it like we fix bad English on SO. @BillWoodger

Comment: Even in the main site I think that english with a "please translate this" warning might be ok, but only if the question or answer is a good one.

Comment: Victor, if you use any other language on SO, you get a bunch of downvotes and delete votes in seconds. *Sometimes* a good soul steps in and translates the content, but SO is for English content. And our site is for Portuguese content.

Comment: Ach! I shouldn't rush. I just updated my COBOL answer with English... I should let this discussion conclude first, @bfavaretto

Comment: Yes, in other sites they have a very aggressive and intolerant attitute: "if you don't write in english, you are an inferior being that should die an horrible death now and go to hell forever". I really don't think that we should do the same. Of course if someone is really abusing or writes very low quality questions and answers in english without any respect with the fact that this is a portuguese community, we should stop it quickly. But if the user is clearly in good faith, let's just help him.

Comment: I agree we should be more tolerant, but that doesn't mean we should be dealing with content in other languages. IMHO – but if you disagree you are an inferior being that should die an horrible death now and go to hell forever :)

Comment: @BillWoodger I was the good soul this time :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, that looks really nice. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Você deveria responder primeiro em português. Deixe então sua resposta original em inglês abaixo. Se você disser que não tem o português como língua materna, isso será suficiente para outros tentarem ajudar em qualquer erro na tradução. Talvez você até possa usar um site de tradução on-line.

Se quiser, fazendo deste modo também lhe ajudará a aprender português. Como já dito, nós somos muito mais tolerantes a pessoas de idiomas estrangeiros que o SO ou outros sites.

Mas o objetivo primário do SOPT parece ser apoiar os que falam português e mas acham difícil entender o inglês. Assim, responder apenas em inglês pode não fazer muito sentido...

Tradução abaixo em inglês, seguindo meu próprio exemplo:

You should answer first in Portuguese. Then let your original answer bellow. If you state that you don't speak Portuguese as your original language that will suffice to anyone other try to help your mistranslation. Maybe you can use an on-line translation site to help you.

If you want, doing this way will also help you learning Portuguese. As stated, we are much more tolerant to foreigners speakers than SO or other sites.

But the primary objective of SOPT seems to support Portuguese speaking people that find hard to understand English. So answering only in English may not make sense at all...

Answer (score 2):

Did you note what just happened?

You are in a Portuguese community (I can't say if this is Brazilian or Portuguese)... so you wrote it in portuguese, what is perfectly understandable. And of course you didn't wrote totally right, so a user corrected your portuguese.

And it also happens at the original StackOverflow, sometimes when I post a question there, I always get my question corrected... which is good, because it can helps other people to better understand your question.

So don't worry, I am Brazilian, and sometimes people correct my questions here at PT StackOverflow.

**Sorry for bad my extremely English**

Comment: "Sorry for bad English" :D

Comment: Você viu o que aconteceu? Você está um uma comunidade que fala português, em embora não tenha problema em escrever **também** em inglês**, o correto seria escrever em português.

Comment: Just to know, did you note that you are more than three years late to the party? Not that this is either a good or a bad fact, but it is something that should be noticed.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é que tinha aparecido no "Debates mais ativos", nem tinha olhado a data xD

Comment: @Breno Se é assim, eu fico imaginando que tipo de critério que o site usa para decidir quais são os debates mais ativos... XD