# Perguntas com frases em inglês estão sendo rejeitadas antes mesmo de serem criadas

Tags: debate, suporte

Ao criar a [pergunta sobre unicórnios](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149/por-que-nos-nao-ganhamos-unicornios) aqui no meta, minha pergunta foi automaticamente rejeitada por possuir uma frase em inglês no final. A mensagem dizia que a pergunta não estava nos padrões exigidos de perguntas. Mas não deu nenhuma orientação que pudesse indicar que o problema era a frase em inglês no final. Para conseguir passar pela verificação automática eu removi a frase no final e depois de postar a pergunta editei e adicionei a frase.

Tenho uma pergunta e uma sugestão.
Pergunta: Qual é o critério para identificar que uma pergunta feita não está nos padrões do site? Pois não pode ser que proibindo uma frase específica estejamos limitando muito o que pode ser escrito nas perguntas?

Sugestão: Acho que seria melhor deixar claro para quem está fazendo a pergunta que não é apropriado escrever em outras línguas que não seja o português. Pois, até então, parecia que éramos um [pouco mais tolerantes a isso.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/648/2652)

Comment: teria como reproduzir essa mensagem e tirar um printscreen? Talvez tenha sido implementado recentemente algum algoritmo que verifique se existem muitas palavras em inglês e emita essa mensagem, pq algumas semanas atrás varias perguntar que deveriam ir para o SOen estavam caindo aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Ainda assim perguntas em inglês devem ser permitidas aqui no meta.

Comment: @perdeu Creio que seja só copiar e colar a pergunta numa nova. Eu não fiz isso pois pensei que poderia ou duplicar a pergunta e acabar não conseguindo deletar ou talvez fosse alguma norma que eu não estava sabendo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal foi o que eu pensei, por isso estou questionando o critério para considerar uma pergunta apropriada ou não.